# Is it possible to obtain session id key in Unity to use with Bing Map request?

Tags: unity-game-engine, bing-maps

Usually to get the session id key to use with Bing Map request instead of the Bing Maps Key, we would use one of the available control ( Bing Maps AJAX Control 7.0, Bing Maps Silverlight Control, Bing Maps WPF Control, and Bing Maps for Windows Store apps) to request a session id depending on the situation.

Since the app we are currently working with was developed with Unity (the game engine) and use the REST imagery api from Bing Map to request tile data and display them,  every request for map tile is counted as a billable transaction since there is no session id because there is no control available.

We would like to reduce the amount of billable transaction the app receive every time the user browse the map and the only way to do so is to have a session id key.

Is there a way other than with the default control provided to obtain a session id key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is technically possible but not authorize in the terms of use since the session key mechanism is only to be used with the provided map controls among those offered by the platform (AJAX, SL, WPF and WinStore app controls).

**MSDN reference:**

See the MSDN for more information:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff859477.aspx

With quoted useful information:

> This transaction is not billable if the service request is made using a session ID from an AJAX Control, Silverlight Control, WPF Control, Windows Store app for JavaScript, or Windows Store app for C#, C++, or Visual Basic session.

**Terms of use:**

And see the Terms of Use regarding the session information, article 4.9.b: 
https://www.microsoft.com/maps/product/terms.html

**Regular use, best practices and samples:**

For any other regular and authorized use cases, see the blog post that explains how to optimize the calls and transactions:

http://blogs.bing.com/maps/2013/02/14/bing-maps-rest-service-tips-tricks/